# Why isn't this code finding my textbox in my ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview with an EditTemplate.  If I have one item in the listview, the following code throws a null exception:

```
if((TextBox)this.lvwColors.EditItem.FindControl("txtColor")) != null)
{
   this.Color =    
   ((TextBox)this.lvwColors.EditItem.FindControl("txtColor")).Text.Trim();
}
```

It does not throw an error if I have two items in my listview.

The other strange thing is that it only throws an error when on a production server, but when I am testing locally, I do not get the error.  Does anyone know why this behavior might exist?

Here is EditTemplate part of the markup:

```
<EditItemTemplate>          
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtColor" runat="server" 
                 Text='<%#   Eval("Color").ToString().Trim() %>'
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Please post more of your code--the *full* line from above and the markup it is referencing.

Comment: I updated some markup and code.

Comment: Added GridView example to my answer, please confirm if you are using a GridView or ListView and edit you question accordingly.

Comment: I am using a listview, but it still FindControl still returns null when in fact I know the textbox exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ListView.ItemEditing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemediting.aspx):

**ListView:**

```
 protected void yourListView_ItemEditing(Object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    ListViewItem item = yourListView.Items[e.NewEditIndex];

    if((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtColor") != null)
    {
       this.Color =    
          ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtColor")).Text.Trim();
    }

  }
```

Comment: I don't see an event called ItemEditing, is it the same as the RowEditing Event.

Comment: Here is the list of ListView events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx

Comment: I think are using a GridView and not a ListView

Comment: Oops sorry, I mean to say I did not see a RowEditing event, but only a ItemEditing event.  I tried your code and when it hits the part with the FindControl, it is null.  I know that it is not though.